seaborn boxplot: make x-axis a continous number scale instead of categorical
I use the following code to plot a sns boxplot
import seaborn as sns

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(30, 10), dpi=600)
sns.boxplot(x='A_bias', y='A_freq', data=bias_sen_df)
plt.show()
plt.close()

getting

As you can see, x-axis have values e.g. 10 and 50, which have different interval than other data points but seaborn just treated them as a categorical label instead of a number.
How to make x-axis a continous number scale instead of categorical, so that numbers space out according to the actual spacing of a continuous number scale?

Did you try native_scale=True, which was recently added?
